# html embedded pdf loading indication

Tags: html, pdf, embed

I've embedded some PDF files in one of my websites which I only intend to use locally.
Currently I use this code to do this:

```
<object class="ebookDetailImg"
  data="ebooks/<?php echo $ebook ?>"
  type="application/pdf">

    <embed class="ebookDetailImg"
      src="ebooks/<?php echo $ebook ?>"
      type="application/pdf" />

</object>
```

Because the file is saved somewhere on my own network, it loads the file almost instantly but actually rendering the file can still take up some time.

When this happens on other websites, it shows the user a loading sign in the bottom left corner but that doesn't happen in my case and I would like to have it.

Even though this website is meant to be used locally and only by me, that doesn't mean it shouldn't be pretty!

I'm talking about this loading indicator: http://s11.postimg.org/yhsw4t1w3/pdfloader.jpg

Any thought on what I'm doing wrong/forgot to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually being caused by the files loading to fast and not having enough time to display to load icon. When I tried it from my production server which isn't on the same network as I am, it did show the loading icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way that you could work around this is by requesting the PDF download using an AJAX request.

There is an answer posted here that I haven't tested myself but seems the correct way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199517/file-download-progress-bar-in-browser.

To be honest, from the user's point of view the browser/PDF viewer usually have some kind of progress bar in place.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this will only show the progress of the download but since the download is almost instantly (local network) this isn't an issue here.

It's really the rendering time that takes a few seconds (as in the grey box has already been drawn, it only needs to draw the pages inside of it). it's during this time that I would like to see the build in (I think?) progress indicator.

Comment: Ah I see. In that case probably not JS then. I suspect that the biggest issue will be detecting how long the forthcoming PDF will take to download. Perhaps consider this http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html